# Webview HTML5 Audio length

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, audio, webview

I am developing a Webview Android application using HTML5.
The app contains plenty of html5 audios.
The problem is that I noticed on some "4.1" low budget android tablets that if the audio is less than 45 seconds it doesn't play at all when clicked. When the audio track is more than 45 seconds the audio is played as expected.

Is there an android application, codec, library or plugin that overrides the chrome's default player? On some audios I am using the jquery library mediaelement.js. But that didn't pan out for "small" audios.